# Testing HCE payment application

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I am doing a POC on HCE based payment.

I have an NFC enabled phone to run the app but do not have NFC enbaled card reader. Is there any way I can emulate a card reader (at POS)?

thanks,
iuq

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing banking payment application, then you`ll need POS terminal simulator, may be issuer simulator and any USB NFC reader connected to your PC.
MasterCard terminal simulator can be freely downloaded from their site https://www.terminalsimulator.com/